# Complex Analysis - Liouville's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently doing a past paper and have come across a tricky question. I would ask my lecturer but he doesn't reply to emails over Easter!

Let  $f$ 
 be a non-constant entire function, and let $g(z) = z  f(z)$

$(i)$ Explain why there exists $r > 0$ such that $0$ is the only zero
of $g$ in $D(0, r)$

$(ii)$ Prove that the function $1/g$ is meromorphic on $D(0, r)$,
where $r > 0$ is as in the previous part

I believe (ii) is just recognizing that finitely many zeros of $g$ implies that there are finitely many poles and therefore meromorphic.
However I'm stuck in (i). I believe it has something to do with $f$ being dense in *C* since it is non-constant and entire. How do I, therefore, show that the only zero of *g* is at zero itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zeros of non-constant analytic functions (with connected domain) are isolated points. So, since $g(0)=0$, there has to be a $r>0$ such that $g$ has no other zero in $D(0,r)$. And then $\frac1g$ is meromorphic there, since it is the quotient of two meromorphic functions.

Comment: Why must the quotient of two meromorphic functions be meromorphic?

Comment: Also, if f is entire then doesn't that mean f is NOT meromorphic?

Comment: Since g has 1 zero in D(0,r) then 1/g has only 1 pole in D(0,r). But how do we know 1/g has also finitely many removable singularities. Isn't a meromorphic function a function with finitely many poles and removable singularites?

Comment: The meromorphic functions are those functions which can be expressed as the quotient of two holomorphic functions. It follows from this that the quotient of two meromorphic functions is again meromorphic and also that every entire function is meromorphic.

Comment: The only singularity of $\frac1g$ in $D(0,r)$ is at $0$. Elsewhere there are no singularities.

Comment: Thank you sir. I love portugal. obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose not. Then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a point $z_n\in D(0,1/n)$ such that 
$$
g(z_n)=0
$$
So, $z_n\to 0$ and $g(z_n)=0$ for any $n$. What does this tell you about $g$? Can such a thing be possible if $f$ is nonconstant?

If $g$ is holomorphic and nonzero in a region, 
$$
\frac{1}{g(z)}
$$ 
is holomorphic in the region, with derivative 
$$
-\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)^2}
$$
The region here will be the $D(0,r)\setminus \{ 0\}$.

Comment: I don't understand the significance of that being the derivative of g.

Comment: I wanted you to see you could even compute the derivative explicitly.